# Overriding the abstract method TimerTask.Run()

Tags: java, overriding, abstract-class

I have a problem in overriding the method run from the class TimerTask.

Here is my code:

```
public class PGameCore 
{

    Toolkit toolKit;
    Timer   timer;

    public PGameCore(int clockIntervalInSeconds)
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new CoreTimer(), 1000 * clockIntervalInSeconds);
    }

    class CoreTimer extends TimerTask
    {
            public void Run()
            {
                System.out.println("BEEEP :)");
                toolKit.beep();
            }
    }

}
```

The problem is in the row:

```
class CoreTimer extends TimerTask
```

I`m using Netbeans. It says:
"PGameCore.CoreTimer is not abstract and does not override abstract method run() in TimerTask."

Answer (score 6):

*It says: "PGameCore.CoreTimer is not abstract and does not override abstract method run() in TimerTask."*

Your method name is `Run` while it should be `run`.

Comment: Question is not stupid. Not accepting the answer that helped most might go into that direction, though :D

Answer (score 2):

run, not Run - Java is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Use eclipse or netbean IDE. It will solve many of your compile time problems.

In above case you should use `run` method. This is case sensitive. You have used `Run` where R is capital which is incorrect method.

Keep one habit to avoid such errors. Use **Camel** case while writing method name and use **Pascal** case while writing Class name.